# How to know the yearly variation/ check the mean value per year, for different years?

Tags: r, time-series, mean, standard-deviation

I have this data containing the animal ID, and measures of 15N and 13C for different years (2012-2017).

I need to obtain the mean and +-SE for 15N and 13C, then plot the yearly variation of each using these means.

In other words, I need to find the mean 15N and the mean 15C (with the standard error) for each year, then plot this, all using R.

```
ID      Year    N       C
BVC002  2012    11,03   -16,3
BVC003  2012    12,6    -17,34
BVC004  2012    14,5    -11,3
BVC005  2012    14,08   -9,52
BVC00   2012    11,86   -15,34
BVC008  2012    11,5    -16,7
BVC009  2012    15,1    -15,7
BVC010  2012    13,25   -15,08
BVC011  2012    10,3    -14,6
BVC012  2012    17,8    -13,5
BVC014  2012    12,3    -11,9
BVC015  2012    10,83   -17,59
BVC117  2012    13,7    -9,6
BVC122  2012    13,3    -8,9
BVC127  2012    10,2    -17,5
BVG640  2012    12,6    -17,5
BVG642  2013    10,91   -16,52
BVG653  2013    12,03   -15,4
BVH013  2013    12,52   -15,9
BVH014  2013    12,17   -14,16
BVH015  2013    14,34   -15,31
BVH017  2013    12,06   -16,98
BVH041  2013    13,91   -14,6
BVH042  2013    11,56   -18
BVH044  2013    11,49   -16,61
BVH045  2013    14,29   -12,9
BVH046  2013    10,11   -16,5
BVH050  2013    10,35   -17,5
BVH051  2013    11,98   -12,13
BVH052  2013    12,77   -17,32
BVH053  2013    10,92   -15,31
BVH054  2013    12,85   -16,85
BVH055  2013    9,46    -15,47
BVH056  2013    11,54   -18,54
BVH058  2013    12,27   -16,84
BVH074  2013    13,6    -15,74
BVH101  2013    10,32   -17,93
BVH105  2013    13,05   -17,14
BVH107  2013    12,48   -17,19
BVH115  2013    12,61   -15,33
BVH117  2013    11,56   -14,97
BVH121  2013    15,1    -14,9
BVH122  2013    12,39   -16,26
BVG162  2013    11,6    -16,23
BVG165  2014    11,81   -15,68
BVG172  2014    11,51   -12,12
BVG173  2014    14,26   -16,48
BVG174  2014    14,01   -15,62
BVG175  2014    9,19    -17,26
BVG176  2014    13,86   -15,9
BVG180  2014    11,77   -16,6
BVG348  2014    11,65   -18,1
BVG353  2014    13,17   -15,05
BVG354  2014    10,75   -12,44
BVE191  2014    13,95   -16,69
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you tried using packages `dplyr` (functions `group_by` and `summarise`) and plotting using package `ggplot2`? Their documentation is excellent: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise

Comment: Also take care that you seem to be using decimal comma rather than decimal point. See documentation of `read.csv` to make sure data were imported correctly (argument `dec`)